# Markov chain separation element and message

Tags: markov-chain

From Bishop's book I know an observed variable in a Markov Chain does work as d-separation element. What I am more uncertain about is what happens to the message itself.

In the sum-product algorithm, instead of summing over that specific variable, I just use the observed value for the potential function multiplied by the incoming message, but **how does this make what is after independent with what is before?**

Won't the input message still be the summation on the previous variable of the potential function multiplied by its incoming message?

---

$$\circ_{x_1} - \circ_{x_2} - \bullet_{x_3} - \circ_{x_4} - \bullet_{x_5}$$

and I'd like to proof that

$$x_2 \perp x_5 \mid x_3.$$

I can write

$$p(x_2)=\frac{1}{Z}\mu_\alpha(x_2)\mu_\beta(x_2),$$

where

$$\mu_\alpha (x_2)=\sum_{x_1}\psi_{1,2}(x_1,x_2)$$

and

$$\mu_\beta  (x_2)=\psi_{2,3}(x_2,\hat{x}_3)\mu_\beta(\hat{x}_3).$$

The demonstration *ends* by saying that the only contribution of $x_5$ would be about the normalisation constant $Z$. Why? Won't that $\mu_\beta(\hat{x}_3)$ be computed using $x_4$ and $x_5$ recursively? I'm missing something... :/ I don't see how the observation is "separating" anything.

---

I try to explain my self more clearer. Let's say $x_3$ is unobserved, so that:

$$\circ_{x_1} - \circ_{x_2} - \circ_{x_3} - \circ_{x_4} - \bullet_{x_5}$$

Let's then evaluate $\mu_\beta(x_2)$:

$$\mu_\beta(x_2) = \sum_{x_3}\psi_{2,3}(x_2,x_3)\mu_\beta(x_3),$$

$$\mu_\beta(x_3) = \sum_{x_4}\psi_{3,4}(x_3,x_4)\mu_\beta(x_4),$$

$$\mu_\beta(x_4) = \psi_{4,5}(x_4,\hat{x}_5)\mu_\beta(\hat{x}_5),$$

$$\mu_\beta(\hat{x}_5) = 1.$$

This means that

$$\mu_\beta(x_4) = \mu_\beta(x_4,\hat{x}_5)$$ and

$$\mu_\beta(x_3) = \mu_\beta(x_3,\hat{x}_5),$$ hence

$$\mu_\beta(x_2) = \mu_\beta(x_2,\hat{x}_5),$$

which tells me $x_2$ is dependent of $x_5$.

Now, if $x_3 = \hat{x}_3$, I will have that

$$\mu_\beta(x_2) = \mu_\beta(x_2,\hat{x}_3,\hat{x}_5)$$

so, to me, it still looks as dependent of $x_5$... Please help.

Comment: Why would someone down-vote my question? Perhaps s/he did not have enough background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything in my question is right. There is just a step missing, which will conclude the demonstration correctly. So, the last point that was escaping me, was about what does the summation over $x_3$ entail.

---

Let's start with the case where $x_3$ is observed and takes the value of $\hat{x}_3$.

$$\circ_{x_1} - \circ_{x_2} - \bullet_{\hat{x}_3} - \circ_{x_4} - \bullet_{\hat{x}_5}$$
$$p(x_2)=\frac{1}{Z}\mu_\alpha(x_2)\ \mu_\beta(x_2),$$ where
$$\mu_\alpha (x_2)=\sum_{x_1}\psi_{1,2}(x_1,x_2)$$ and
$$\mu_\beta  (x_2)=\psi_{2,3}(x_2,\hat{x}_3)\ \mu_\beta(\hat{x}_3).$$
Now $$\mu_\beta(\hat{x}_3) = \sum_{x_4}\psi_{3,4}(\hat{x}_3,x_4)\ \mu_\beta(x_4)$$ and
$$Z = \sum_{x_1}\sum_{x_2}\sum_{x_4} \psi_{1,2}(x_1,x_2)\ \psi_{2,3}(x_2,x_3)\ \psi_{3,4}(x_3,x_4)\  \psi_{4,5}(x_4,\hat{x}_5) =\\
= \mu_\beta(\hat{x}_3)\sum_{x_1}\sum_{x_2} \psi_{1,2}(x_1,x_2)\ \psi_{2,3}(x_2,x_3)$$
$$\require{cancel}\therefore p(x_2\mid\hat{x}_3,\hat{x}_5) = \frac{\mu_\alpha (x_2)\ \psi_{2,3}(x_2,\hat{x}_3)\ \cancel{\mu_\beta(\hat{x}_3)}}{\cancel{\mu_\beta(\hat{x}_3)}\sum_{x_1}\sum_{x_2} \psi_{1,2}(x_1,x_2)\ \psi_{2,3}(x_2,x_3)}=p(x_2\mid\hat{x}_3)$$
$$\Rightarrow x_2 \perp x_5 \mid x_3\ \ \ \ \square$$

---

In the other case, where $x_3$ is unobserved

$$\circ_{x_1} - \circ_{x_2} - \circ_{x_3} - \circ_{x_4} - \bullet_{\hat{x}_5}$$

the $\sum_{x_3}$ will not allow us to *extract* the $\mu_\beta(\hat{x}_3)$ term above that we managed to cancel out. Therefore $$x_2 \not\perp x_5 \mid \varnothing\ \ \ \ \square$$

Answer (score 0):

The statement "Won't that μβ(x^3) be computed using x4 and x5 recursively?" is true if x^3 were an unknown message but once observed it has collapsed to a specific value and the property of μβ being a function means you don't have any other dependency (as it has no other arguments)

Solving this multi-step markov was factorised into solving each step in "message space".  Each message encodes a pdf function.  Usually approximated by mean and variance only.  The "product" step is a product of probabilities .. the combined message usually has a mean like a "certainty" weighted average and the variance generally reduces as the solution converges.